# Is it possible to connect with remote desktop but not be able to ping to the same machine?

Tags: networking, ping, remote-desktop

It seems I have this weird issue I can't really understand. I am able to connect to a remote computer (windows machine) with remote desktop perfectly but I am not be able to ping to it. When I ping I get timeout all the time. It is the same ip address and I am using the same computer, so there are no firewall issue I think. From what I know ping is using it own protocol (different than TCP and UDP) so you don't ping to a precific port

Comment: maybe question for superuser.com ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. The system administrator, and the network administrators (of the *several* networks you need to use to access the remote machines), are able configure their boxes to disable [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol). Then `ping` does not work, but HTTP or `ssh` (or whatever protocol your remote desktop uses) could work.

<sup>ICMP is often disabled for security reasons, and to lower the load on the remote computer. It makes slightly harder to find the remote host.</sup>

Comment: Intresting. Do you know if such thing applies for the Amazon ec2? The remote machine is a amazon instance

Comment: Probably yes. If you really care, ask the Amazon support (but you might have to pay to get some good explanation, and it might not worth the money)

Comment: Why would someone disable ping? It seems weird to me.